# How to add Promise to event handler in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, amqp, q

Now I want to wrap [`amqp`](https://github.com/postwait/node-amqp) with Promise [`Q`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q), here are the codes

```
Sender.prototype.createConnection_ = function () {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    this.con_ = amqp.createConnection( this.connectOpt_, this.implementOpt_ );
    deferred.resolve( this.con_ );

    return deferred.promise;
}

Sender.prototype.connectionReady_ = function() {
    var deferred = Q.defer(),
      self = this;

    self.con_.on('ready', function() {
        console.log('connection is ok now');
        deferred.resolve(self.con_);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}

Sender.prototype.createExchange_ = function() {
    var deferred = Q.defer(),
      self = this;

    this.con_.exchange( this.exchangeName_, this.exchangeOpt_, function ( ex ) {
        self.ex_ = ex;
        deferred.resolve(self.ex_);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}

Sender.prototype.exchangeReady_ = function() {
    var deferred = Q.defer(),
      self = this;

    this.ex_.on('open', function() {
        console.log('Sender: exchange opened');
        deferred.resolve(this.ex_);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}

Sender.prototype.connect_ = function() {
    var self = this;
    return self.createConnection_()
            .then( self.connectionReady_() )
            .then( self.createExchange_() )
            .then( self.exchangeReady_() )
            .catch( function(err) {
                console.info( err );
            });
}
```

When I want to invoke `connect_`, there is one error show that `this.ex_` is `null` in the `exchangeReady_` function.

I want to how to add `Q` in the event `open` and `ready` function ?

Comment: If you're willing to use a modern promise library you can get rid of the ugly `.bind`s in the answer. (And probably better performance)

Comment: Could you please give me some modern promise library?

Comment: Bluebird for instance is the fastest and has facilities to handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling your functions immediately, rather than passing a function reference to the `.then()` handlers.  `.then()` takes a function reference, not a promise as an argument.   Change to this:

```
Sender.prototype.connect_ = function() {
    return this.createConnection_()
            .then( this.connectionReady_.bind(this) )
            .then( this.createExchange_.bind(this) )
            .then( this.exchangeReady_.bind(this) )
            .catch( function(err) {
                console.info( err );
            });
}
```

The `.bind(this)` lets you pass a function reference (something the `.then()` infrastructure can call later) and still have it bound to `this`.

---

It looks like you may also have binding issues when you pass callbacks like this:

```
amqp.createConnection( this.connectOpt_, this.implementOpt_ );
```

These callbacks will not stay bound to `this`.  Instead, use `.bind()` like this on any callback that is method:

```
amqp.createConnection( this.connectOpt_.bind(this), this.implementOpt_.bind(this) );
```

The same issue exists several other places in your code.

Comment: Added another example of an object binding issue when passing callbacks.

Comment: So `.bind` the returned function?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - my mistake.  This returns a promise, not a function.  I'll withdraw my original comment.  The `self` can be removed.