# Adding a parameter to a function in .then() breaks the behaviour of a promise in JS

Tags: javascript, promise

*getPosts()* loops through an array of posts, builds LIs and places them inside document.body. Works ok.

```
function getPosts(num){ 
  let output ='';
  posts.forEach((post, index)=>{
     output += `<li>${post.title} (${num})</li>`;
  });
  document.body.innerHTML += output;
}
```

*createPost()* returns a promise which waits 3 seconds (to simulate client-server delay), adds a post to the array and resolves.

```
function createPost(post){
     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       setTimeout(()=>{
          posts.push(post);
          const error = false;          
          if (error){
             reject ('Error happened!');
          }else{
             resolve();
          }
       },3000);
    });
 }
```

The following works as expected. Three LIs are returned, with *(undefined)*:

```
createPost ({title: 'Post Three', body: 'Post Three'})
.then(getPosts);
```

But when getPosts inside .then has a parameter, it is fired without waiting for promise to resolve:

```
createPost ({title: 'Post Three', body: 'Post Three'})
.then(getPosts(1));
```

Why?

https://codepen.io/Marko36/pen/LJoRYN

Comment: please, use code snippets instead of links to external services

Comment: Other references in addition to the one this is marked a duplicate of: [How to add promise to event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28956946/how-to-add-promise-to-event-handler-in-javascript/28957092#28957092), [Promise example not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31063778/simple-promise-example-with-bluebird-and-coffeescript-works-half-the-time/31063832#31063832)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `then` you give a callback function.

`then(getPosts)` will be called with the argument given: `getPosts(result)`

But `getPosts(1)`is immediately resolved.

What you want is `()=> getPosts(1)`

---

Edit to clarify the difference between the two syntaxes:

```
const foo = getPosts(1)
//foo is the _Result_ of immediately calling getPosts(1)
//so in your case an array with some objects in it, or undefined
foo(); //CRASH BOOM BURN - foo is not a function

const bar = () => getPosts(1)
//bar is a lambda that can be called to execute getPosts(1)
//At some point in the future or whenever -which is what your then-Block does
const posts = bar(); //Hooray, we have posts
```

Comment: Thanks. Why does getPosts(1) and ()=> getPosts(1) behave differently?

Comment: I tried to explain it a bit better - see my edit